# TFS and Unit testing: How to find all failing test caused by my recent undelivered changes?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, tfs

Is there any easy way to get all failing test caused by my recent undelivered TFS-changes? And not any tests that was allready failing... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given these two premises:

- you're using Visual Studio 2010 Premium or Ultimate
- your unit tests are written using MSTest

then you could use the [Test Impact View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264992.aspx) to look at and run the unit tests that are affected by the code changes made since the last time the solution was built on your local machine.

**Related resources:**

- [Test Impact Analysis in Visual Studio 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phuene/archive/2009/12/07/test-impact-analysis-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx)
- [Choose the Right Test with Test Impact Analysis](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dalaqab/archive/2009/06/10/choose-the-right-test-with-test-impact-analysis.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Other than walking each test, there is no way to know. This is why you generally set up a "get latest" before check in and then run tests.

On the other side of the equation, you should have run the tests locally prior to getting latest and ensured all tests were passing. This rules out your code alone being a problem and leads to two possibilities:

1. Somebody else broke the build - see logs
2. Your code does not play well with other people's code (or there's does not play well with yours)

If you follow the discipline of get latest, test (red - confirm you are not starting broken), add test code for new feature/defect, test (red, as code/fix not in place), code, test (green) refactor, test (green), include latest, test (ensure no breaks with any code someone else has checked in), check in once green.

If you end up with a break after get latest, you check to see if someone else checked in broken code (if tests have to pass before checkin, which I advise, this can only be done on purpose). If broken, either fix the code or have it fixed. NOBODY should leave a build in a broken state. Then re-get latest and try again.

Since it sounds like the discipline above is not being followed, it will be hard to determine whose code broke the build, which means you have to fix it all, or fix the stuff you know you touched and have the other guy fix his damaged goods. Either way, it has to be fixed. Then discipline has to be applied, either via process or changing the check in policies.

Comment: In our company, in order to make sure that failing tests are *always* due to your latest changes (and there are not any tests that were already failing) we have deployed the "Gated-Check in" trigger in the DEV-branches.
So each commit leads to a Build, where all tests are executed.

So you 'd just have to Get Latest & start working. Any problems arising are problems you have just now implemented.@Andreas: This might not be a direct answer to your question, but if you experience a lot of these situations, it might be worth considering to change your dev-process.